# HashSet allows duplicate item insertion if hashCode() is not overridden

Tags: java

```
class temp {
int id;

public int getId() {
  return id;
}

temp(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
      return true;
  if (obj == null)
      return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
  temp other = (temp) obj;
  if (id != other.id)
      return false;
  return true;
}
}

public class testClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      temp t1 = new temp(1);
      temp t2 = new temp(1);
      System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
      Set<temp> tempList = new HashSet<temp>(2);
      tempList.add(t1);
      tempList.add(t2);
      System.out.println(tempList);
}
```

The program adds both the elements to the Set. I was shocked at first because while adding methods to set, equals method is invoked.

But then I overrode the hashCode method:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }
```

And then it did not add. This is surprising as the Javadoc of Set and add() method says that it checks only equals() while adding into the Set.

And this is the javadoc for add():

```
/**
     * Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
     * More formally, adds the specified element <tt>e</tt> to this set if
     * this set contains no element <tt>e2</tt> such that
     * <tt>(e==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e2==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;e.equals(e2))</tt>.
     * If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
     * unchanged and returns <tt>false</tt>.
     *
     * @param e element to be added to this set
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set did not already contain the specified
     * element
     */
    public boolean add(E e) {
      return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

Then I realized that the HashSet is implemented as a HashMap and in the map, the hashCode of the object is used as the key. So, it is treating them using different keys if you dont override hashCode.

Shouldn't this be in the documentation of the add() method or that of HashSet?

Comment: The whole reason the hashCode() function exists is for hash based collections. How should a collection "know" what hash function to use if you don't defined it?

Comment: I found out that the equals() method of class temp is never called in this case (tried sysout), so the JVM invokes the default equals() if we do not have hashCode() implemented in order to fulfill the contract of JVM specification. Interesting !!!!!!!

Comment: It only calls `equals` if the `hashCode()`s are the same. It doesn't call the default equals if you override it.

Comment: Object.equals and hashcode both mention they must both be overridden and explains the hows and whys. If every class that used hashcode/equals explained the same thing we would have many many copies of the same thing instead of one centralized copy.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Ohhkkk so thats how it is done. Thanks for the info it is really helpful.

Comment: @DhwaneetBhatt why Object type parameter in `equals();` if you are still casting ?

Comment: @UnKnown: I did not get what you are asking.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It kind of is documented. See the documentation for [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), where it says on `hashCode()`:

> If two objects are **equal according to the equals(Object)** method, then
>   calling the **hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer** result.

Additionally the following is found in the documentation for the `Object.equals(Object)` method:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that **equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes**.

In other words, if with your class when `instanceA.equals(instanceB) == true` and `instanceA.hashCode() != istanceB.hashCode()` you are in fact violating the contract of the Object class.

Comment: I always read that equals() and hashCode() both should be overriden but i never knew not doing it would produce unpredictable results. Also since the documentation of Set and add() method specifically say that overriding equals method is necessary but no mention of hashCode(). The contract exlpains it all.

Comment: @DhwaneetBhatt I'm glad i was able to be of assistance. Indeed when storing objects in Java's sets, implementing both of the methods is important. I'm not saying that it should be overlooked when there is no apparent or immediate need to do so. A proper (as per the contracts) implementation can, however, be quite non-trivial to dream up.

Comment: @DhwaneetBhatt Note that Java Set is an interface. add(Object) method is defined in the interface and is unaware of implementation. Different implementations of the set require different informations from contained objects. HashSet queries object hash code while TreeSet requires some way of comparing object and doesn't care about hash code.

Answer (score 14):

Just take a look also at `equals()` documentation:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that **equal objects must have equal hash codes**.

The fact is that `equals()` and `hashCode()` are strongly linked. Both should always be considered when working with one of them to avoid these consistency issues.

Comment: Jack in question why equals(); method have Object type in parameter? even still casting then why not direct temp class type parameter?

Answer (score 8):

If you override equals() you **must** override hashCode() as well.

There are some restrictions placed on the behavior of equals() and hashCode(), which are enumerated in the documentation for Object. In particular, the equals() method must exhibit the following properties:

- Symmetry: For two references, a and b, a.equals(b) if and only if b.equals(a)
- Reflexivity: For all non-null references, a.equals(a)
- Transitivity: If a.equals(b) and b.equals(c), then a.equals(c)
- Consistency with hashCode(): Two equal objects must have the same hashCode() value

See [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html) for more details.

Comment: How interesting that every thing everywhere is so inspired by Mathematics ;)

Answer (score 1):

They (the javadoc guys) might have pre-assumed that when they say (at the documentation of `add()` method in `HashSet`)

```
(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))
```

the `hashCode()` is inherently equal for both of them.

Comment: Agreed, though the presumption is valid since one using a Set should be familiar with the related methods, such as Object.equals(Object), which according to the documentation of the respective method is strongly linked to the Object.hashCode() method.